# what is the best way of doing a remote development using PyCharm community version

Tags: python, pycharm

PyCharm Professional has a nice feature of remote development -- developing codes on your local machine and running them on a remote server. Without PyCharm Professional, what would be a good way of mimicking this feature? I really like PyCharm so I won't give up for another IDE. I used to package the codes into an egg file and sftp it to a remove server but this is cumbersome, since I have to make the setup files, etc.

Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Comment: If the project is open source, you can request a Professional license for open source usage.

Comment: pycharm is amazing ... it is totally worth just getting the professional one .... you dont necessarilly have to renew every year.... you get a fallback license that always works for the last pycharm version of the year you bought

Comment: [This is a related feature request for PyCharm.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19752)

Answer (score 0):

use winscp to keep your remote directory in sync

install ssh

add external tool of "run remote" (I assume this is available)

`ssh user@remote.com -t "cd /path/to/proj && python myproj.py"`

if you have ssh keys setup it should just work ... if not you will probably be prompted for a password