# How do I use remote deployment (e.g. push local copies on save) in Pycharm if the remote cluster requires using duo sign?

Tags: pycharm

## How do I use remote deployment (e.g. push local copies on save) in Pycharm if the remote cluster requires using duo sign?

I used to be able to push on save with the cluster I am using. However, now the cluster requires duo sign in. I still want to be able to push on save from my local to the sever. How do I do that?

I checked the options but I can't see anything obvious that might be helpful to me:

[image]
[image]

---

I am aware that there might be remote development options (vs-code has something like that). If that is available for pycharm that would be a ok alternative but even if it works I was hoping to have the clusters in sync with my local so to have less copies of everything lying around. I have to admit I need to research and try this option more but I'm unsure if that is the option I want. But if the old workflow does not work it might be the only viable alternative.

Some links I need to read:

- [PyCharm: Remote Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32211813/pycharm-remote-development)
- [PyCharm - can't use remote interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159539/pycharm-cant-use-remote-interpreter)
- [what is the best way of doing a remote development using PyCharm community version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396067/what-is-the-best-way-of-doing-a-remote-development-using-pycharm-community-versi)
- [Remote development in Pycharm - without local copies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287453/remote-development-in-pycharm-without-local-copies)

ideally the debugger and all the features of pycharm still work.

---

related links:

- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009663879-how-do-I-use-remote-development-if-the-remote-cluster-requires-using-duo-sign-in-
- [How does one configure the vs-code SFTP to work on save when security duo is activated on the remote cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62286320/how-does-one-configure-the-vs-code-sftp-to-work-on-save-when-security-duo-is-act)
- [How do I use remote deployment (e.g. push local copies on save) in Pycharm if the remote cluster requires using duo sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63796803/how-do-i-use-remote-deployment-e-g-push-local-copies-on-save-in-pycharm-if-th)
- https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-do-I-use-remote-deployment-e-g-push-local-copies-on-save-in-PyCharm-if-the-remote-cluster-requires-using-duo-sign
- https://www.reddit.com/r/pycharm/comments/iove6i/how_do_i_use_remote_deployment_eg_push_local/

Comment: Did you find a solution? If so, could you add it?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to set up the usual Deployment configuration (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-deployment.html#preferences-of-the-selected-deployment-configuration) and then go into the configuration that you created. Click on the `...` icon. That takes you to another window. Test the connection there, then a pop up window appears. It asks for a passcode. Use the passcode from your phone.

Make sure the sever wants a passcode and not a push. Otherwise, idk what pycharm might do.